# operation overloading * (both left side and right side)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class Mat

```
class Mat
{
 ..
..
..
   friend Mat& operator*(Mat s1,int elem){
     s1.multiWith(elem);
     return s1;
}
};
```

now it will work for 
m1*2
but how to make it work with
2*m1

Answer (score 4):

> now it will work for m1*2 but how to make it work with 2*m1

Provide another overload for it.

```
class Mat
{
..
    friend Mat operator*(const Mat& s1, int elem) {
        Mat ret = s1;
        ret.multiWith(elem);
        return ret;
    }
    friend Mat operator*(int elem, const Mat& s1) {
        return s1 * elem;
    }
};
```

BTW1: `operator*` should return `Mat` by value, not by reference.
BTW2: You might want to change the parameter type of `s1` to const reference to avoid copying.
BTW3: If `Mat::multiWith` is not `private` `operator*` don't have to be `friend`.

Comment: look like it will work, will V after checking when i will get home, ty

Answer (score 3):

`a*b` operator is supposed to return a new object, not a reference to `a`.

Correct syntax to declare an `operator*` within the class is:

```
class Mat
{
   ..
   ..
   ..
   Mat operator*(int elem){
        Mat res = *this;
        res.multiWith(elem);
        return res;
   }
};
```

Then, type of the left parameter is necessarily the current class (here: left parameter of `a*b` is necessarily a `Mat` instance).

Now if you declare the operators outside the class, you are free to choose any type for left and right parameters:

```
class Mat
{

};

Mat operator*(const Mat& left,int right){
     Mat res;
     // do res=left*elem
     return res;
}

Mat operator*(int left,const Mat& right){
     Mat res;
     // do res=left*right
     return res;
}
```

Comment: and what if the Mat is Template... how can i write the out of my class operators?

Comment: @JohnnyF: That should probably be a separate question as you OP did not mention that. However, just add `template <...>` before the operator declaration. An operation declared externally to a class can be template.